# What is the Best practice to migrate data from Cassandra table to new table having materialized views?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax

I am in process to **migrate** data from cassandra table(having old schema with faulty partition keys etc.) which do have materialized view created on it TO another table (redefined table) having materialized view as well.

So i redefined schema and insert data into new table.
What would be faster, efficient way to insert data to new table if we take scenarios as

1. **Just create new table and do not create its MV until all data is inserted i.e. create MV at the end.**
2. **Create both at once and insert data on it**

My perception is that **option 1** would be faster as 2nd option would keep updated MV (behind the scene it creates table that will be updated on each insert).

> **NOTE: question is more related to performance while migrating data with or without MVs. created before or after.**

Answer (score 0):

If you can, follow the 1st variant - you may able to load data faster as materialized view adds overhead to every operation. After data is loaded, create materialized view, and check status with `nodetool viewbuildstatus`

Comment: if i create MV afterwards then how about creation of tables and data that cassandra does behind the scene, kindly elaborate more.assuming i have normally (-500KB+) of text JSON stored in column over 500K rows.

Comment: Cassandra will index the existing data automatically, but it may take some time if you have a lot of data. I recently tested DSE 5.1 (Cassandra 3.11 + fixes) and indexing of ~1M records took not much time (< 1 min)